# iframe printing problem (safari)

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing, safari

I am trying to print an iframe with this function:

```
   function printIframe(id) {

      iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[id] : document.getElementById(id);
      ifWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
      iframe.focus();
      ifWin.printPage();

   }
```

This code successfully prints iframes in all browsers.  The problem is that safari will not print some images.  Some images will print, whereas others will just print blank spaces.

Has anyone ran into this problem before?

Comment: Safari has some weird print CSS bugs - hold on and I'll see if I can sober up that part of  my brain ...

Comment: Does the page in question have a "print" stylesheet?  If so, check to see if it has any "@page" rules. Safari does not deal with those very well.